Removing the root view element, does not work correctly in older version of iOS
I have a custom TabView and ObservableObject - TabViewCoordinator which
I have a custom TabBar and TabBarCoordinator that can remove it from the screen, this works great on iOS 18 but on earlier versions it leaves a white rectangle in place of the tabbar (see screens), try running the code below
iOS 18
iOS 16
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    enum Selection {
        case home, search, myShelves, profile
    }
    @State private var selectedTab: Selection = .home
    @StateObject private var tabBarCoordinator = TabBarCoordinator()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("Screen 1")                    
                    .tag(Selection.home)
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                
                Screen2()
                    .tag(Selection.search)
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    .environmentObject(tabBarCoordinator)
                
                Text("Screen 3")
                    .tag(Selection.myShelves)
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Spacer(minLength: 700)
                        
                        Text("Screen 4")
                        
                        Spacer(minLength: 700)
                    }
                }
                .tag(Selection.profile)
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
            }
            if !tabBarCoordinator.isTabBarHidden {
                Divider()
                CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .offset(y: 45), removal: .offset(y: 45)))
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
final class TabBarCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    func show() {
        if isTabBarHidden == true {
            isTabBarHidden = false
        }
    }
    
    func hide() {
        if isTabBarHidden == false {
            isTabBarHidden = true
        }
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var isTabBarHidden: Bool = false
}

extension MainView {
    struct CustomTabBar: View {
        @Binding var selectedTab: Selection
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                tabBarItem(selection: .home, title: "Screen 1", image: Image(systemName: "globe"))
                Spacer()
                tabBarItem(selection: .search, title: "Screen 2", image: Image(systemName: "globe"))
                Spacer()
                tabBarItem(selection: .myShelves, title: "Screen 3", image: Image(systemName: "globe"))
                Spacer()
                tabBarItem(selection: .profile, title: "Screen 4", image: Image(systemName: "globe"))
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.top, 9)
            .background(Color.white)
        }
        
        private func tabBarItem(selection: Selection, title: String, image: Image) -> some View {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 6, height: 6)
                    .opacity(selectedTab == selection ? 1 : 0)
                
                image
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                
                Text(title)
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedTab = selection
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Screen2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var tabBarCoordinator: TabBarCoordinator
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Screen 2 \n push Screen 2.5") {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                    Text("Screen 2.5")
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onAppear {
                    tabBarCoordinator.hide()
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    tabBarCoordinator.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried changing tabBar in onAppear screen 2.5, just before calling screen 2.5, and also tried force redraw by adding and changing @State property in Screen 2.5, no effect

Sometimes you have to male the toolbar visible before you can hide it

The native TabBar seems to be removed correctly, as if the problem is with the custom one
